# cannot start apache tomcat service in windows server

Tags: apache, tomcat, service, cron

I install the service using the service.bat /catalina and it shows up in services.msc just fine, but whenever I go attempt to start it, even with domain admin or local admin rights, it errors out, and eventlogs are useless because there is next to zero information on the actual root cause of why it won't start...

[service won't start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqcL5.jpg)

//// update

okay there is something wierd I figured out, if I set it to anything at or below 1024 mb it works and the services start in services.msc on window server all versions.
but if I set it to anything more, even at 1025mb, it will not start up, UNLESS I do exact multiples of 24, like 1024, 1048, 1072 etc... this holds until it reaches a limit...

On a windows server 2008 32bit that only has 4GB total, the limit is around ~1600-ish but suprisingly on a windows server 2008 r2 64bit with tons of memory, the limit was only around ~1200

This is the exact same tomcat5.exe and tomcat5w.exe and installed as service with exact same way... so it makes no sense whatsoever....

Why does memory increase past the 1024mb mark need to be in precise 24 mb increments?
and why is there a different "wall", with the LOWER spec'd machine able to reach much higher (1600mb) than the higher spec'd one with more ram (~1200)

I read something about JVM needing contingious memory but this is just nuts and doesn't make any sense whatsoever

Comment: Is there any anything in Tomcat logs ?

Comment: Are you sure you do not use a 32bit JRE on a  64bit OS?

Comment: Is there any reason you are still using that ancient version of Tomcat?

Comment: i did update in update